# Loading SKLearn 20_newsgroups dataset into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

**Python**: I'm trying to load a sklearn.20_newsgroups dataset **sklearn.utils.Bunch** into **pandas** dataframe.

[I downloaded  datasets the below link](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/20news-19997.tar.gz)

```
categories = ["alt.atheism", "alt.atheism" ,"comp.os.ms-windows.misc" , "comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware",
                "comp.sys.mac.hardware" , "comp.windows.x","misc.forsale", "rec.autos","rec.motorcycles",
                "rec.sport.baseball","rec.sport.hockey", "sci.crypt","sci.electronics", "sci.med","sci.space",
                "soc.religion.christian","talk.politics.guns" ,"talk.politics.mideast","talk.politics.misc" ,"talk.religion.misc"]

docs_to_train = sklearn.datasets.load_files("/home/Documents03-04-2019/dataset/20_newsgroups", 
                                      description    = None, 
                                      categories     = categories,
                                      load_content   = True,
                                      encoding       = 'ISO-8859-1',
                                      shuffle        = True,
                                      random_state   = 42)

The below code I treid.

docs_to_train.keys()
data1           = pd.DataFrame(docs_to_train.data, columns=docs_to_train.target_names])
data1['Target'] = pd.Series(data1=docs_to_train.target, index=data1.index)
```

**Desired output**
 I ran the below similar kind of  code its working similarly i need newsgroups like a dataframe format.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
data = pd.DataFrame(cancer.data, columns=[cancer.feature_names])
data['Target'] = pd.Series(data=cancer.target, index=data.index)
```

Comment: What is your error or problem?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html

Comment: I am  getting the error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (18997, 1), indices imply (18997, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of your keywords reference unrelated code: you write `cancer` or `data` instead of `data1`, and there's an unmatched `]`.

Try this:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(docs_to_train.data, columns=[docs_to_train.target_names])
data1['Target'] = pd.Series(data=docs_to_train.target, index=data1.index)
```

If that doesn't work, try this instead of the second line:

```
data1['Target'] = pd.Series(data=docs_to_train.target)
```

Comment: Finally got the solution thanks for your suuport @Peter_Leimbigler

`data= pd.Series(docs_to_train.data)`



`data=pd.DataFrame(data)`



`data.columns = ['Data'] + data.columns.tolist()[1:]`



`data['target'] = pd.Series(docs_to_train.target)`

Comment: @TRINADHNAGUBADI, glad to see you found a solution!